# Configure Programmer's Notepad as the Editor in Visual C++

Tags: c, visual-studio-2010, visual-c++

Can some one please tell me How to configure the visual compiler with with programmers notepad editor..

Comment: It looks like you are trying to compile C code with a C++ compiler. Please don't attempt to do so. (It won't work anyway, in the general case.)

Comment: @user3477950 visual c++ will compile C code just fine with a .C extension (or if explicitly told to).

Comment: @user3623905 I have edited the title to match the wording of your question. You do want to use PN in VC++, not compile C in PN don't you?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not familiar with Programmer's Notepad, but I have done this with Vim so the same procedure should work.

You need to add Programmer's Notepad to Visual C++ as an external tool:

1. Choose Tools/External Tools...
2. Click Add
3. Fill in the details

You will need to enter the full path to Programmer's Editor for the Command.
When you are entering the Arguments, you can use the following variables if Programmer's Notepad can use them in its arguments:

- $(CurLine) - the current line
- $(CurCol)) - the current column
- $(ItemFileName) - the current filename, without the extension
- $(ItemExt) - the current file's extension

There is more information on MSDN here: [How to: Run External Tools from Visual Studio](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/9814d200%28v=vs.100%29.aspx)

If by any chance you want to do this the other way round and run the Visual C++ compiler from Programmer's Notepad, the process is quite similar. I found this page on the PN website:

[Capture compiler output](http://pnotepad.org/docs/howto/capture_compiler_output/)

Comment: No, I'm pretty sure that's the opposite of what was wanted.  From the original title and question, I think he wanted a way to invoke the compiler from his editor (like setting `makecmd` in Vim).

Comment: @Ben Voigt, hmmm, you may be right. I have added a paragraph about that.